# Vagrant box run python and wait

Tags: python, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am currently provisioning a vagrant box and running a python script;

```
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "python first.py", :privileged => false
```

Now this works and it fires but in the python script itself, i am asking for a 
`raw_input` through the python script. However, the inputs just gets skipped when provisioning the vagrant.

```
==> default: Checking if box 'box' is up to date...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Do you want to download the database? [Y/n] Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' (or 'y' or 'n').
==> default: Do you want to download the database? [Y/n]
==> default: Traceback (most recent call last):
==> default:   File "first.py", line 110, in <module>
```

Would anyone have any idea on why this is happening and how i can prevent it and wait for a response.

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant runs the script through ssh connection so there's no stdin so you cannot run this command (or you can run them but they wont have the expected output)

one way to workaround this case would be to ask the question during the Vagrantfile itself and pass the answer to the script. something like this

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ....
  print "Do you want to download the database? [Y/n] Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' (or 'y' or 'n')."
  answer = STDIN.gets.chomp

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "setup.sh", :args => [ answer ]
  ....
end
```

the main drawback is that the question is asked everytime you run a vagrant command so it can be a bit painful.